# Is there a way to send and receive packets on the same port in pktgen?

Tags: networking, dpdk

In pktgen-dpdk is there any way to configure it to send and receive packets in the same port? for example port 0 send packets and receive it as it sends

Answer (score 0):

@caetanocolinTorres simple answer is `no special configure parameter in pktgen to do so`.

explanation:

1. DPDK pktgen is build on top of DPDK library.
2. all the features of HW device is extracted by DPDK library.
3. there are some DPDK NIC which `may support Internal loopback`
4. to enable this one has to configure DPDK ports, which means edit `PKTGEN source code and recompile`.

Note: always share

1. OS version
2. dpdk version
3. NIC driver, firmware
4. original source if modified as the snippet.